# How To Host More Than One Silverlight User Controls In ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-3.0

I am creating an ASP.NET web site application in Visual Studio 2010. I have added one Silverlight application in my project. It has one user control mainpage.xaml. Every Silverlight application when added in ASP.NET project creates on testpage.xap which can be used for adding that control in our web page.

When I add another user control in the same Silverlight application, it doesn't create second test page, so how can I use that control in web page?

Is it true that we can create only one Silverlight control in one Silverlight application?

Comment: You can have multiple silverlight applications hosted in your ASP.net site and the silverlight project doesn't need to be in the same solution as the web solution.
You can display different UI based on what gets passed into init params
You can use a class library to share different user controls between silverlight applications.  There is not enough information in your question to figure out which of these you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you on a bit of a path to the wrong place here.

The test-page that Visual Studio is so nice (or intrusive) to create for you, is a "link" to the XAP file. An XAP file contains a Silverlight application and inside that application you can have several usercontrols, pages and whatever you can imagine creating in Silverlight.

Without knowing the context of why you are using Silverlight there is a few options, if you only want one Silverlight project you could use the Navigation Framework inside Silverlight. Though beware there might be dragons to deep-linking into a Silverlight application from an architectural view. Another option would be going for a plain parameterizing on your app via the built-in initParam ([intro](http://www.pochet.net/blog/2010/06/09/passing-parameters-to-a-silverlight-xap-application/)) you can set in the html for the object tag.

Without being a complete moron, I would suggest that you give yourself a bit of time to read up on how Silverlight actually works, cause it seems like you have misunderstood the platform a bit (that is debateble depending on who you talk to though)